# ExcelDataReader ConfigureDataTable Error

Tags: vb.net, exceldatareader

I'm attempting to use `.asDataSet()` with a configuration:

```
Dim x_config As New ExcelDataSetConfiguration
Dim table_config As New ExcelDataTableConfiguration With {
                                                            .UseHeaderRow = True
                                                         }
x_config.UseColumnDataType = True
x_config.ConfigureDataTable = table_config
'ERROR: Value of type 'ExcelDataTableConfiguration' &_
'cannot be converted to 'Func(Of IExcelDataReader, ExcelDataTableConfiguration)'.

basis_data = reader.AsDataSet(x_config)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ConfigureDataTable to this.

```
x_config.ConfigureDataTable = Function(tableReader) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration() With {
     .UseHeaderRow = True
    }
```